# How to add "unique key prop" to child using map function

Tags: reactjs, key, jsx, array.prototype.map

I have seen other people ask similar questions to this and I have tried implementing the answers they received. But I am still getting a console error. I mean the code is working as expected I just hate having console errors.

Here is my code

```
const Accordion = () => {
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

    const toggle = index => {
        if (clicked === index) {
            //if clicked question is already active, then close it
            return setClicked(null);
        }

        setClicked(index);
    };

    return (
        <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#441d0c', size: '25px' }}>
            <AccordionContainer>
                <FaqContainer>
                    {FaqData.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <>
                                <QuestionWrapper onClick={() => toggle(index)} key={index}>
                                    <h2>{item.question}</h2>
                                    <span>{clicked === index ? <FiMinus /> : <FiPlus />}</span>
                                </QuestionWrapper>
                                {clicked === index ? (
                                    <AnswerDropdown>
                                        <p>{item.answer}</p>
                                    </AnswerDropdown>
                                ) : null}
                            </>
                        )
                    })}
                </FaqContainer>
            </AccordionContainer>
        </IconContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

and the console error I get:

**Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**

To me it looks like each child DOES have a unique key, What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key should be set at the root object of your map.
In order to fix the warning, you can replace the react fragment (**<>**) by a div and set the key like this:

```
{FaqData.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <div key={index}>
            <QuestionWrapper onClick={() => toggle(index)}>
                <h2>{item.question}</h2>
                <span>{clicked === index ? <FiMinus /> : <FiPlus />}</span>
            </QuestionWrapper>
            {clicked === index ? (
                <AnswerDropdown>
                    <p>{item.answer}</p>
                </AnswerDropdown>
            ) : null}
        </div>
    )
})}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. This explanation was very helpful and exactly what I needed to understand my issue. I used your explanation with @the_previ 's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a React Fragment short syntax that can't have keys.
See: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax

You have to use the complete syntax:

```
{FaqData.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>

      ...

    </React.Fragment>
  )
})}
```

Comment: Thank you I did not understand this. I used your answer combined with the first one.